# show updated picture in inertiajs. (not refreshing the image link)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have an app that updating a picture. but after updating the picture it's showing last picture not the new one.

this is the code:

```
<!-- Header -->
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <!--  Header File Input -->
    <input
        ref="headerInput"
        type="file"
        class="hidden"
        id="headerInput"
        @change="updateHeaderPreview"
    >

    <InputLabel for="Header" value="Header" />


    <!-- New  Header Preview -->
    <div v-if="headerPreview" class="mt-2">
        <h1>preview</h1>
        <span
            class="block w-96 h-96 max-w-full max-h-full bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center"
            :style="'background-image: url(\'' + headerPreview + '\');'"
        />
    </div>

    <!-- Default Header Preview -->
    <div v-else class="mt-2">
        <h1>Default</h1>
        <img src="/storage/header.png" class="w-96 h-96 max-w-full max-h-full object-cover">
    </div>


    <SecondaryButton class="mt-2 mr-2" type="button" @click.prevent="selectNewHeader">
        Select A New Header
    </SecondaryButton>

    <InputError :message="form.errors.header" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

so when updating the header picture its showing `default` (else) with last image.
Only with fully reload the `default` will change it's picture.